# How to fetch api with javascript to display data?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am trying to build an API with JavaScript to fetch data from this URL for JSON data: img, a, c , but below codes threw back an error of

> application.js:10 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: `data.forEach` is not a function

(why is the `forEach` method not defined) can you help?

```js
var results = document.getElementById("results");

fetch("https://www.mangaeden.com/api/list/0/")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((data) => {

    data.forEach((result) => {

      const movies = '<li><img src="' + result.im + '" alt=""><h3>' + result.a + '</h3><p>' + result.c + '</p></li>';
      results.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", movies);

    });
  });
```

```json
{
  "a": "shoujo-apocalypse-adventure",
  "c": [
    "Adventure",
    "Drama",
    "Psychological",
    "Sci-fi",
    "Seinen",
    "Slice of Life",
    "Tragedy"
  ],
  "h": 156,
  "i": "5c410d31719a16035a4647cc",
  "im": "4a/4a1f2a595e0e84e62f6ceddf3946274478928ca99e8df86bc6511b6e.png",
  "ld": 1547822837.0,
  "s": 2,
  "t": "Shoujo Apocalypse Adventure"
},
```

Comment: Because your data is an object, not an array.

Comment: Is this the response? When I checked, it responses with something like: `{
  "end": -1, 
  "manga": [
    {
      "a": "joshiraku", 
      "c": [
        "Comedy", 
        "Shounen", 
        "Slice of Life"
      ], 
      "h": 0, 
      "i": "5bfdd0ff719a162b3c196677", 
      "im": "4e/4e55aeda6ba2044eb2762124688b61e74f24880515e71827f1f1e2c4.png", 
      "ld": 1543389646.0, 
      "s": 2, 
      "t": "Joshiraku"
    },
]}
}`

Comment: @jonrsharpe the `,` at the very end may indicate it is an element of an array. However in that case saying it is "the Json file:" is not entirely correct.

Comment: @tevemadar and if it was an array, you wouldn't get that error

Comment: @MoshFeu yes! this is the response.when i did simple fetch but without displaying.

Comment: @jonrsharpe oh, it not an json file??i've changed it.

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't JSON, which isn't *quite* the same as a JSON file anyway. It's JSON, but *not* representing an array.

Comment: @developing `forEach()` works on arrays, the `[...]` thing. Yours is a single object, `{...}`. Simply remove the loop statement, and use `data` in place of `result`.

Comment: @developing By the way, how did you make it works? Don't you get "cors" error?

Comment: @MoshFeu hi mosh, 


var results = document.getElementById("results");

fetch("https://www.mangaeden.com/api/list/0/")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((data) => {

    data.forEach((result) => {

      

    });
  });
 i did this and open console and it fetched successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response is not an array (`[]`) but an object (`{}`) and object has no method `forEach`. I guess you meant to run the `forEach` on the entries, which in this case is under `data.manga`.

```js
var results = document.getElementById("results");

fetch("https://www.mangaeden.com/api/list/0/", {
    mode: 'cors'
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((data) => {

    data.manga
      .filter(movie => movie.c.includes('Action') || movie.c.includes('Adventure'))
      .slice(0, 10).forEach((result) => {

      const movies = '<li><img src="https://cdn.mangaeden.com/mangasimg/' + result.im + '" alt=""><h3>' + result.a + '</h3><p>' + result.c + '</p></li>';
      results.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", movies);

    });
  });
```

```html
<ul id="results"></ul>
```

https://jsbin.com/gecusi/edit?html,js

**Note**: In the example I `slice` the array because there are ~6.7k movies and I don't want to block the browser.

Comment: hi mosh thanks for answering! although the images aren't showing , is there any way to show it?

Comment: also, what does  mode: 'cors' do?

Comment: A. The path in the json is relative (not includes the domain, for example). If you know the base path, it can be done.

Comment: B. `cros` means that the request allowed to be sent to a different domain - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful. I'm not sure how it works for you without that.

Comment: hi Mosh, i understand what you mean, in this case, how'd you suggest to find the base path?

Comment: It's in their api (scroll down) https://www.mangaeden.com/api/. I updated my answer.

Comment: @developing thoughts?

Comment: hi Mosh, thank you so much, you really helped a lot!

Comment: @developing Glad to hear :) Can you [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer so it may help to other people? Thanks and good luck.

Comment: hi Mosh, just wondering do you know what's the reasons why it only shows the image when called.slice(0, 10) but when i did .slice(5,50) or got rid of the slice method, the images aren't showing but threw back 403 error?

Comment: it should work on every image, shouldn't it? thanks!!

Comment: just wondering how do i also filter the .c for just "action"&"adventure ", thank you!

Comment: `.slice(5,50) ` works for me. Maybe it something with your network (because it a lot of images?).

Comment: I just updated my answer. You can filter items with, well, [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: thanks, Mosh, not sure!it appears that images arent showing on my side with 403 error, any way to accelerate the speed of images? (i am running on a rails app)

Comment: it doesnt seem like it works on mine - kept throwing me 403 error for every single image.

Comment: it seems like only the first .slice(0,10)images without filter function would work.

Comment: I did some tests and I also get error (503 - service not available) when there are many images in the list. I guess it because of the issues with their api (service not available).

Comment: Sure, any time :) Good luck.